# Musiela parameterization

Tags: estimation, yield-curve

I have a question regarding the proof of the Musiela parametrization for the dynamics of the forward rate curve.  If $T$ is the maturity, $\tau=T-t$ is the time to maturity, and $dF(t,T)$ defines the dynamics of the forward rate curve, then the Musiela parametrization defines the forward rate dynamics $$d\bar{F}(t,\tau)=dF(t,t+\tau)$$.

My question is regarding the next step in the working of the Musiela parametrization.  All of the literature I've looked at explains the next line by simply stating that a "slight variation" of Ito is applied.  The line reads:

$$d\bar{F}(t,\tau)=dF(t,T)+\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}dt$$

Can someone please clarify what variation of Ito is being used here?  I'm not following.  The parameters to $d\bar{F}$ do not include an Ito drift/diffusion process, so why is Ito being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$dF(t,T)$ describes the dynamics of the rate of a particular forward contract as time $t$ moves forward to a fixed expiration $T$.

$d\bar F(t,\tau)$ describes the dynamics of the rate at a particular point on the yield curve as time moves forward.

The differential $\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}dt$ is simply the difference between holding the expiration time $T$ constant in the case of $F$ and moving it ahead with time $t$ to stay at the same point $t+\tau$ on the yield curve in the case of $\bar F$.

Somewhere underlying all this is a drift-diffusion process, but it isn't stated explicitly in your equations.

$dF(t,t+\tau)$ is a "total" differential of $F$ with respect to a simultaneous change in both its arguments.  This becomes the sum of a partial differential w.r.t. change in the first argument only, $dF(t,T)$, and a partial differential w.r.t. change in the second argument only, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}dt$, as time moves forward.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I think I follow your explanation, but I'm looking for more of a mathematical derivation of the first and second terms for $d\bar{F}(t;\tau)$.  Mathematically, how would you explain going from the first equation I've listed in the original post to the second?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain a little more.

Comment: Thanks for the revision.  That's along the lines of what I was thinking, but I think I'm mis-interpreting the notation somehow.  Here's how I understand breaking up the total differential into the sum of partials:

$$dF(t,T)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} dt + \frac{\partial F}{\partial T} dT$$

Comment: T is a function of t, $T=t+\tau$, so applying the chain rule on the second term yields:

$$dF(t,T)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} dt + \frac{\partial F}{\partial T} \frac{\partial T}{\partial t} dT$$

with $\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=1$

Comment: As I wrote that last comment, I realized that I don't think I can write $dT$ as a differential since T is a function.  So that explains the second term.

For the first term though, your answer is implying that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}dt = dF(t,T)$.  If that's correct, that's where I'm getting lost.

Thanks again for your help with this.

Comment: I believe that is correct, and $\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=1$ if you want to stay at the same point on the yield curve.  I suppose I haven't explained it as clearly as possible...